# Enable HTTPS to my site running on Ubuntu Ec2

Tags: angularjs, amazon-ec2, https, ubuntu-16.04

I have a domain in Godaddy. 
The website is developed in AngularJS and hosted in Ubuntu 16 EC2. 
I pointed the domain with EC2 IP address in godaddy, and it works fine. 
Need help in configuring HTTPS for my website.

Comment: probably more relevant to https://serverfault.com

Comment: [Use a free cert](https://letsencrypt.org/getting-started/) from Let's Encrypt but I agree with @avigil - serverfault.com is a better place for administrative type questions.

Answer (score 0):

First you need to buy SSL certificate from SSL provider like GoDaddy. To get SSL you have to provide them .csr file.

To Generate CSR and private key file use below command

```
openssl req –new –newkey rsa:2048 –nodes –keyout private.key –out server.csr
```

Provide this server.csr file to SSL Provider/GoDaddy when they ask to submit it. They will return you certificate files after some approvals.

After getting certificate you have to add these files in apache config file

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
DocumentRoot /var/www/html2 // your document root folder on server
ServerName www.yourdomain.com // your domain
SSLEngine on
SSLCertificateFile /path/to/certificate.crt // certificate file 
SSLCertificateKeyFile /path/to/private.key // your private file
SSLCertificateChainFile /path/to/DigiCertCA.crt // CA bundle file
</VirtualHost>
```

both `certificate.crt` and `DigiCertCA.crt` will be provided by SSL provider

Here is complete process:

https://www.digicert.com/csr-ssl-installation/apache-openssl.htm

http://www.elinuxbook.com/step-by-step-ssl-configuration-in-apache-web-server/

Answer (score 0):

A slightly easier solution is to create an elastic load balanacer, add the web server as its target group, order a free certificate via the Amazon Certificate Manager, and add it to the load balancer.